# Why can't we multiply by 0 scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Gaussian elimination, why can't we multiply an entire row by 0? My teacher said it's 'destroying information' but can it be explained in a more mathematical way? is it because we're mapping to the kernel? does it have anything to do with the annihilator?

Comment: The equation $x+2 = 5$ is equivalent to $3x+6 = 15$, but it is not equivalent to $0x+0 = 0$. And you want to transform your equations in such a way that they remain equivalent to what they used to be, since otherwise the solutions of the resulting system won't be guaranteed to still solve the original system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the linear system $A {\bf x} = {\bf b}$ as a system
$$\sum_k A_{i k} x_k = b_i$$
of scalar equations indexed by $i$, then multiplying the $i$th row of the augmented matrix $(A \, | \, {\bf b})$ by $0$ corresponds to replacing the equation $\sum_k A_{i k} x_k = b_i$ (for a particular $i$) with the equation $0 = 0$. Unless all of the $A_{ik}$ are zero, these two equations have different solution sets, and hence making that replacement produces a system that may have a different solution set than the original system.

For an easy but illustrative example, take $A = I$, ${\bf b} = {\bf 0}$. What is the solution set of this equation? If we replace the $i$th equation, namely $x_i = 0$, with the equation $0 = 0$, what is the solution set of the revised system?